# Creating customized labels using FLutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I want to create the following label using Flutter. How do I go about doing this? 
[image]

Is there an Icon class that creates this kind of label?

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929637/how-to-set-the-shape-of-a-button-with-conical-border/53931532#53931532

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a label instead of a button. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I want the left part of the image you shared to look exactly the same as the right part. How do I achieve this using this code: 

 path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(arrowDepth, size.height / 2);
    path.close();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CustomClipper](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) to clip your widget.

I have a package for that and you can find the LabelClipper [here](https://github.com/figengungor/clippy_flutter/blob/master/lib/src/label_clipper.dart)

Comment: Thanks. I want to display the ticket clipper and I added the following code 

SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          Ticket(
            radius: 30.0,
            child:  Image.asset("lake.jpg"),
            ). 

Plus, why does the child contain an image instead of a text?

Comment: child's type is Widget. So you can put any widget you like.

Comment: If I add new Text("Something"), only the text shows up. The shape doesnt show up at all

Comment: You have to wrap your Text with a Container and give it a color and padding. It doesn't provide shapes.It just clips whatever you give to it.